# adding response to nesting field with another field rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

I have a main table that hosts an Applications Table and a nested table of Tests with an input of questions. I'm trying to add another table that answers the questions posed by the nested table.

My problem is that it won't save the reply in the answer table.

[image: Explanation of what the heck!]

Here's my code:

answers.controller.rb

```
  class AnswersController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @application = Application.find(params[:application_id])
        @answer = @application.answers.create(params[:answer].permit(:reply))
        @answer.user_id = current_user.id if current_user
        @answer.save

        if @answer.save
            redirect_to application_path(@application)
        else
            render 'applications/new'
        end
    end
 end
```

applications.controller.rb

```
class ApplicationsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_application, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show   ]

    def index
        @applications = Application.all.order("created_at DESC").limit(3)
    end

    def new 
      @application = current_user.applications.build
      @application.tests.build
    end

    def create
        @application = current_user.applications.build(application_params)

        if @application.save
            redirect_to @application
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def show
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        if @application.update(application_params)
            redirect_to @application
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end


    def destroy
        @application.destroy
        redirect_to root_path
    end

    private

    def find_application
        @application = Application.find(params[:id])
    end

    def application_params
        params.require(:application).permit(:name, :description, tests_attributes: [:id, :question, :_destroy])
    end

    def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    redirect_to root_path
    end
end
```

Models:

answer.rb

```
class Answer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :test
  belongs_to :application
  belongs_to :user
end
```

application.rb

```
class Application < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user

    has_many :tests
    has_many :answers

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :tests, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

    validates :name, :description, presence: true
end
```

test.rb

```
class Test < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :application, required: false
  validates :question, presence: true
  has_many :answers
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :applications
  has_many :answers
end
```

answers.form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([@application, @application.answers.build]) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.text_field :reply %>
        <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-default" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

applications.html.erb

```
<h1><%= @application.name %></h1>
<h4><i><%= @application.description %></i></h4>
<h3>Questions</h3>
<ul>
    <% @application.tests.each do |test| %>
        <li>
            <%= test.question + "?" %>
        </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>

<h2><%= @application.answers.count %></h2>
<%= render @application.answers %>

<%= render 'answers/form' %>

<h6><%= link_to "Back", root_path %></h6>
```

create_answers migration:

```
class CreateAnswers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :answers do |t|
      t.string :reply
      t.references :test, foreign_key: true
      t.references :application, foreign_key: true
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I should've just linked the GitHub repo. I'm terrible at this. I need friends I can ask about this stuff without feeling like a dum dum. Should've graduated college.

Comment: Shouldn't each `Test` have multiple questions, where each question has an  `Answer` that corresponds to it?

Comment: What's the problem here?